# Get specific value from an array an put it in index.erb Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this array:

```
session[:current_user] = { :nickname => auth.info['nickname'],
                                      :image => auth.info['image'],
                                      :uid => auth.uid }
```

The `auth.info['nickname']` stuff comes from a user input that I get from Omniauth Steam. I was wondering how I can put this into my index.erb.

I currently have `<p><%= session[:current_user][:nickname] %></p>` but this is not working. If I use `<p><%= session[:current_user]%></p>` it will display the entire array. How can I just display the :nickname information?

Output with just `session[:current_user]`:

```
{"nickname"=>"Corybantic Walrus", "image"=>"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d45a66fee7932d270ec32d4457d865b485245cf1_medium.jpg", "uid"=>"76561198128055024"}
```

Comment: *not working* not saying more what is the actual problem ?

Comment: Sorry, @ArupRakshit I edited the question

Comment: `session[:current_user][:nickname]` should work. What is the problem with this ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Nothing comes out on the index.erb, whereas when I only use `session[:current_user]` , the whole array comes out

Comment: will you try this `<%= session[:current_user]['nickname'] %>`

Comment: I also have posted the output that I see on the index.erb

Comment: @corybantic use what Athar said, you will be done

Comment: YES that works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have output

```
{
  "nickname"=>"Corybantic Walrus", 
  "image"=>"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d45a66fee7932d270ec32d4457d865b485245cf1_medium.jpg", 
  "uid"=>"76561198128055024"
}
```

so in `hash` you have keys like `String` not  `Symbol`

you must call it like this:

```
session[:current_user]["nickname"]
# or
session[:current_user]['nickname']
```